# How to separate the second comma in string

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
id  address
-----------------------------------------------
1   hyderabad,madhapur,patrika nagar 500072
2   telangana,uppal, ragive gand nagar,517456
3   usa,verginea,va,123093
4   america,new york
5   india
```

Output should be:

```
1     hyderabad,madhapur,
       patrika nagar 500072
2     telangana,uppal, 
       ragive gand nagar,517456
3      usa,verginea,
       123093
4      america,new york
5      india
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more? It's not very clear what you need

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn some details about the expected format of questions on the site. As it is, this question is asking for a solution. The expectation of most questions on Stack Overflow is you have made some effort into a solution and have run into an issue, with your question being about the specific issue. Please attempt to solve this problem yourself before asking for help.

Comment: i want second comma into a next line in a single select list.

Comment: If there is so many columns in select list and address column should be in two lines.as show in output.

Answer (score 0):

This perhaps?

```
DECLARE @string varchar(8000) = 
'id address 1 hyderabad,madhapur,patrika nagar 500072 2 telangana,uppal, ragive gand nagar,517456 3 usa,verginea,va,123093 4 america,new york 5 india'

SELECT newstring = SUBSTRING(@string, d.pos+1, 8000)
FROM (VALUES (CHARINDEX(' ',@string, (CHARINDEX(' ',@string)+1)))) d(pos);
```

Returns

```
1 hyderabad,madhapur,patrika nagar 500072 2 telangana,uppal, ragive gand nagar,517456 3 usa,verginea,va,123093 4 america,new york 5 india
```

Comment: Thanks for help,i want result should be in table format in a single select .please see in above output.